# Filter multiline text in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following response from the server in one of the error scenarios and I would like to capture this and display an error message for the users. The response is

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Service Unavailable - Zero size object</H1>
The server is temporarily unable to service your request.  Please try again
later.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;15&#46;&#&#46;1f636a93
</BODY></HTML>
```

I am getting exactly this same text from Akamai, in the DevTools Response section without any other JSON structure. Now I would like to capture this in my frontend and show a message to the user. Currently, I have the following code:

```
if (error.includes("Service Unavailable - Zero size object")) {
 // error handling
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working for the multiline string with HTML. Can anyone suggest a better method?

Comment: You should probably start by feeding this to a DOM parser.

Comment: Can you include the code for calling the service (fetch, axios, etc.)? What is the status code for the html response?

Comment: I tried your code and it works just fine... Are you sure that the issue is with the multiline HTML? BTW you could use `test` or `match` if you need some regexp

Comment: *"But this doesn't seems to be working for the multiline string with HTML."* `includes` doesn't care about newlines. If those characters exist in the string, in that order, it will find them. If it's not finding them, then those characters *don't* exist in the string in that order. For instance, perhaps there are more spaces between the words, or a hard space is being used, or... (The strings above match, but I'm guessing you've retyped them or some such. `includes` isn't broken, it's not going to miss them if they're there.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your error variable is not a string, though you may be seeing the string in the console when printing it.

A possible fix in this case is:

```js
if (error.toString().includes("Service Unavailable - Zero size object")) {
 // error handling
}
```

For full understanding of the issue you should add the code that is calling the service so that people can understand library and types involved in this request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve this.

There are other, more simple ways than this, but it has its values.

The idea here is that since you get a complete HTML data, you can parse it into an HTML structure.

```js
var msg = '<HTML><HEAD> \
<TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE> \
</HEAD><BODY> \
<H1>Service Unavailable - Zero size object</H1> \
The server is temporarily unable to service your request.  Please try again \
later.<P> \
Reference&#32;&#35;15&#46;&#&#46;1f636a93 \
</BODY></HTML>';

// Actual code starts here.
var parser = new DOMParser(),
    doc = parser.parseFromString(msg, 'text/html'), 
    messageText = doc.querySelector('h1').innerHTML;
if (messageText == 'Service Unavailable - Zero size object') {
    console.log('Error: '+messageText);
} else {
    console.log('Another error: '+messageText);
}
```

The upside in this approach is that you don't need to bother with the text as long as you get the same message structure.